# Use theorem 6.23 to prove that the size of every outer planar graph of order $n \geq 2$ is at most $2n-3$

Tags: graph-theory

Use theorem 6.23 to prove  that the size of every outer planar graph of order $n \geq 2$ is at most $2n-3$

> > **Theorem 6.23**: graph $G$ is outer planar if and only if $G \vee K_1$ is planar

This is what I got

I will prove this by contrapositive, meaning I'll prove if there exist a graph of order $n \geq 2$ such that $m>2n-3$ then $G$ is not outer planar.

let $H= G \vee K_1$ then $n_H \geq 3$ and $m_H >3n-3 >3n-6$  , so $H$ is not planar.

By theorem 6.23, $G$ is not outer planar, so by contrapositive, the above statement is true.

I doubt this reasoning is correct, because it seem too simple. I wonder if anyone can tell me whether there is any flaw that I missed? I saw a proof of this statement in the book that use induction, which is a little bit more complicate than this. Why did the author show the difficult way and leave the easy way for exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof also works to show that outerplanar graphs have at most $2n - 6$ edges.
Which is not true so your feeling is right - something is missing :)

The problem is that $H$ has $n + 1$ vertices.  So you need $m_H > 3(n + 1) - 6$ to show that $H$ is not planar.
But you just need to modify your proof a little bit, by saying $m_H > 3n - 3 = 3(n + 1) - 6 = 3n_H - 6$.

And then I believe everything's fine, even though the proof is indeed quite simple.

I guess the point of the author was to show the power of having nice theorems at hand.

Comment: thank you very much, I feel much better now :D